# How to select only incremental records in BIG QUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a data in my database like as follows

[image: Existing data in the database]

and i am expecting the result like

[image: Expected output from the existing data]

Can anyone please help me how to write a select query for this. it is a kind of incremental load of data

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  You want the earliest version of each record, so:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by empid, empname, sal order by create_time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to detect *changes*, rather than the first occurrence of a set of values, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(sal) over (partition by empid, empname order by create_time) as prev_sal
      from t
     ) t
where prev_sal is null or prev_sal <> sal;
```

This handles salaries that decrease as well as increase.

Comment: Hi Gordon, it is giving me entire data but i am expecting only newly added or modified data. if you look at the data every color is representing one day data, it is like a historical table

Comment: @kalyan4uonly . . . Oh, I see.  `job_process_id` should not be in the `partition by`.

Comment: hint: how about the case when salary goes down to one of previous values :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . I think that comment is more appropriate on the *question*, not on this answer.  You are seeking clarification on what the OP intends.

Comment: no, my intention was to give you a hint as i do believe this was about changes rather than earliest version

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER or ORACLE?

here I try for SQL SERVER
for all records, get the most recent previous record for the employee (if any) and check for changes since then, if none, do not select - therefore, only new or changed records are shown

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tab t1 
    OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP 1 t2.* 
            FROM tab t2 
                WHERE t1.empid = t2.empid 
                        AND t2.create_time < t1.create_time 
                            ORDER BY t2.create_time DESC
        ) IQ
        WHERE IQ.empid IS NULL 
                OR IQ.ename != t1.ename 
                OR IQ.sal != t1.sal
```

Comment: Hi Cato, How to write this in BIG QUERY, could you please help me this